# Why is "version" in the sentence wrong?

Tags: word-usage

Directions: Read the sentences. If the word in bold is used correctly, write C on the line. If the word is used incorrectly, write I on the line.

a. *John Adams's **versions** to his wife were written down and kept by her. (Incorrect.)*
b. There are three different **versions** of what happened. (correct.)
c. I was reading from the children's **version** of the huge novel. (C)
d. On our way down, we took a different **version**, even though it took longer. (I)

**My question is why is (a) wrong?** Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140420/discussion-on-question-by-fanacc-why-is-version-in-the-sentence-wrong).

Comment: If this is from an actual "test" then it's very poorly designed. *Absent context*, both (a) and (d) are incomprehensible / "invalid". But they would both be perfectly natural if prior context clearly established exactly what those ***versions*** referred to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because *without* context it's meaningless to arbitrarily classify some of the cited examples as "correct", and others "incorrect". In the right contexts they're ***all*** valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The test question is better than people are giving it credit for.**

The word "version" has a lot in common with pronouns: it refers to something else. But unlike pronouns, you need to know what that something else is (either directly or indirectly). Let's begin with the definition. From Oxford Languages we learn:

> noun: version; plural noun: versions
>
> 1. a particular form of something differing in certain respects from an earlier form or other forms of the same type of thing. ("a revised version of the paper was produced for a later meeting")
> 2. an account of a matter from a particular person's point of view. ("he told her his version of events")

Here is a copy of your test question. We'll compare each of the four sentences to the definition and explain why each is correct or incorrect.

> Directions: Read the sentences. If the word in bold is used correctly, write C on the line. If the word is used incorrectly, write I on the line. a. John Adams's versions to his wife were written down and kept by her. (Incorrect.) b. There are three different versions of what happened. (correct.) c. I was reading from the children's version of the huge novel. (C) d. On our way down, we took a different version, even though it took longer. (I)

(a) is **incorrect** because we are not dealing with an account of a matter from a particular person's point of view (which implies there are more than one point of view, definition #2) and because we are not dealing with something that differs from an earlier form of the same thing (definition #1, the act of writing it down means we're dealing with a final version). In fact, we don't know what "versions" refers to at all! The word "versions" should not be used here. Acceptable words include: letters, instructions, recipes, jokes, anecdotes, observations, lessons, etc.

(b) is **correct** because we are dealing with the stories or accounts of multiple people (definition #2).

(c) is **correct** because what "version" refers to is clearly included in the sentence ("...children's...huge novel"). It conforms with definition #1 because we can conclude that the "children's version" is a later form of the "huge novel" and differs in certain aspects (abridged and simplified grammar).

(d) is **incorrect.** I really like this example! It's a better-than-average "[trick question](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trick%20question)." You might think it's like (b) because you can deduce (indirectly) from "...even though it took longer" that "versions" refers to a path, road, way, or route, etc. But you can't do that because *roads (etc.) don't have versions.<sup>1</sup>* No route is a "later version" of another route (definition #1) and routes are not expressions of anyone's point of view (definition #2). Example (d) is like example (a) in that the word "version" should be replaced with the actual object under discussion. Examples: road, path, route, etc.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Roads, paths, etc. can have versions, but this requires a bit more explanation than the body of my post will allow. A "version" is an alteration of **one thing.** Different versions of a book, but there's just one book (the children's version of "War and Peace" is still "War and Peace"). Example (d) is discussing (e.g.) different roads, not different versions **of the same road.** However, if an old road was torn up and replaced, then you would have different versions of the same road! However, that isn't the context in example (d).*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem here is that it is an awful question.

I cannot imagine a context where D would be correct, but many people have accused me of lacking imagination.

I can imagine some contrived contexts where A would be correct. Usually, we say "versions of" X rather than "versions" without reference to X. (See sentences 2 and 3.) **ONLY** when X is clear from context do we fail to specify X. Because the first example comes without context, it is not an idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 1):

I must disagree with thew [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/326857/91457) by JBH

The sentences in question are:

> a. John Adams's **versions** to his wife were written down and kept by her. (Incorrect.)
> b. There are three different **versions** of what happened. (correct.)
> c. I was reading from the children's **version** of the huge novel. (C)
> d. On our way down, we took a different **version**, even though it took longer. (I)

The problem that I see is that all four could be correct, depending on the context.

Let us consider the possible context.

a) John Adams did in fact write letters to his wife, describing the proceedings of the Continental Congress, including the debates on the formation of the US Declaration of Independence. These have in fact become a significant historical source. However, his accounts of various events often differ from accounts recorded by others present. These accounts are therefore his **versions** of events. If previous text explained this backgeound, sentence (a) would be correct.

Sentences (b) and (c) are clearly correct with no additional context.

d) Consider the following paragraph:

> Thereare several versions of the route from Jonestown to Hillsboro. On our way up to Hillsboro last week, we took the fastest version of the route, but it was dull. *On our way down, we took a different **version**, even though it took longer.*

Comment: Just to make a point: while you've provided grammatically correct sentences, you're assuming context the test question did not provide (the test question can only be answered within the context of what's provided based on the presumption that it reflects what was taught in a class). And in my neck of the woods, nobody would ever say what you promoted for (d). Just sayin'.

Comment: @JBH I am not **assuming** context. My point is that the sentences in the test question may be incorrect or correct, **depending on** the context. In some contexts (a) and (d) (particularly (a)) **could** be correct. I am pointing out how a suitable context could make those sentences correct, and that since the test apparently gave **no** context, one cannot accurately tell which if any are correct.

Comment: So... this isn't an answer, it's a long comment? The OP provided the answer key. Whether or not any one of the example sentences *could* be something other than what the key says is purely subjective and requires, of course, that context outside the intent of the test is provided. Since the OP provided the answer key, the assertion "one cannot accurately tell..." is false. Analyzing test questions is always based on the question, "what is the instructor trying to teach?" Since the answers were given, that wasn't hard to "accurately tell."

Comment: Let me put this another way. You open your post by saying you disagree with me. All I did was explain why the provided answers were correct. So unless you think there's a problem with my explanations for why the provided answers are correct, what you're really doing is *disagreeing with the answer key.* I'm not sure how that would help the OP, but it would be polite if you were accurate about your complaint.

Comment: It **is** an answer. The question is "*Why is sentence (a) wrong?*" My answer is "That sentence, standing alone, is neither right nor wrong, because it cannot be pronounced so in the absence of context. Moreover, the most plausible context, in the absence of any specified context, is the actual history in which the actual person John Adams figured significantly, and in that context, the sentence is correct." Thus I disagree with the answer key, and with your answer that accepts it. The key is not divinely decreed. I am not primarily trying to help the OP pass that test. [...]

Comment: @JBH [...] I am interested in trying to help ther OP learn English. Your contention that "* act of writing it down means we're dealing with a final version*" is incorrect, a written version is often not final.Your statement that "*we don't know what "versions" refers to at all!*" is precisely why the sentence cannot properly be described as incorrect. We do know the actual history, however, and in that there were multiple versions, including ones written by Adams to his wife.

Comment: That's all your context, David, not the context of the test. It's nice to argue that you're trying to help the OP learn English, but what the OP asked for was help understanding the test. Once again, your problem doesn't appear to be with my answer so much as with the test's answer key. I'm a bit frustrated that you've blamed me for what you seem to believe is a failure in the test. I invite you to delete your first line, at which time I'll delete all my comments.

Comment: I don't **blame** you for anything, JBH I merely disagree with your support of the incorrect answer key, and with the reasons you give for supporting it. You write of two definitions of "version" as if they covered the whole of the meaning of  that word, which they do not. You are free tothink, and say, that my answer is incorrect.